Converting laborious Mathematica expressions into Python source code automatically
I have worked out a (regrettably rather laborious and seemingly irreducible) expression in Mathematica. I'd like to use this expression in a Python script by defining some Python function that takes as input the expression's constants and evaluates it at some value of its dependent variable. For example, given the following Mathematica expression:
expr = A Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2;

I'd expect Python code that looks something like:
def expr(x, A):
    return A * math.sin(x)**2 + math.cos(x)**2

I've tried converting the expression first to one of the possible export options (MathML, LaTeX, and Mathematica source code) and massaging those into Python code (whether by some clever combination of find-and-replace, or using the Python SymPy's library LaTeX interpretation and code generation functionality), to no avail. I've also, of course, tried typing the expression up by hand, however it is quite long and I haven't been able to do so successfully or in a timely manner. Lastly, I tried passing this to a couple of Large Language Models, however each introduced more transcription errors than I could identify.
I had thought that this was what PythonExpression was for, however the following code...
(* Define a Mathematica expression *)
expr = Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2;

(* Convert the Mathematica expression to a Python expression *)
pythonExpr = PythonExpression[expr];

(* Export the Python expression to a file or print it *)
Export["expression.py", pythonExpr, "Text"];
Print[pythonExpr];

...produces a file containing this, rather than the Python source code I had hoped for:
PythonExpression[Cos[x]^2+Sin[x]^2]

There are a couple of similar questions around here, however they seem to all either suggest using SymPy tools (which I have found chokes up on larger expressions, and which I cannot include as a dependency as a consequence of the code base that this Python script will be integrated into) or this third-party function (which I have failed to coax into giving me Python source code for this particular expression).

Addendum
Here's the code in question. I'd like to turn integralResult into a Python function:
xTerm = \[Alpha] + ((2*\[Beta])/(Sqrt[C]*
       Sqrt[4*\[Delta]*\[Gamma] - A^2]))*
   ArcTan[(A + 2*Exp[Sqrt[C] x])/Sqrt[4*\[Delta]*\[Gamma] - A^2]]
zTerm = (1/C)*
  Log[(-\[Gamma]/B)*Exp[Sqrt[C]*x] + (-\[Delta]/B)*Exp[-Sqrt[C]*x]]
xPrime = D[xTerm, x];
zPrime = D[zTerm, x];

squareRootTerm = Sqrt[xPrime^2 + zPrime^2];

refractiveIndexTerm = (A + \[Gamma]*Exp[Sqrt[C]*x] + \[Delta]*
     Exp[-Sqrt[C]*x]);
integrand = Simplify[refractiveIndexTerm*squareRootTerm];
integrand;
integrandExpansion = Series[integrand, {C, 0, 3}];
integralResult = Integrate[integrandExpansion, x];


C is reserved in MMA so I translated that to cc I use MMA to find integrand==((δ+E^(Sqrt[cc]*x)*(A+E^(Sqrt[cc]*x)*γ))*Sqrt[(β^2*E^(2*Sqrt[cc]*x))/(A*E^(Sqrt[cc]*x)+E^(2*Sqrt[cc]*x)+δ*γ)^2+(δ-E^(2*Sqrt[cc]*x)*γ)^2/(cc*(δ+E^(2*Sqrt[cc]*x)*γ)^2)])/E^(Sqrt[cc]*x) and the next step to turn that into a Series takes so long because of all the square roots and exponentials that it finally times out and fails. If I could get integrandExpansion then I'd hand it to you so you could integrate using Python but that doesn't look feasible. So what do we do now? ToPythonFunction might help you.

@Bill Thanks for giving this a try! I'm able to run this without it timing out, although I had to borrow a more powerful laptop in order to do so. If I do f[_x] := integralResult and then ToPythonFunction[f], I get something starting with {"``.function(wolframclient.language.wl.Global.h)", \ "``.evaluate('DownValues[h] = {HoldPattern[h[_x]] :> integralresult}; \ OwnValues[integralresult] = HoldPattern[integralresult] :> \ SeriesData[cc, 0,", as opposed to a Python function. I've been able to use ToPythonFunction with simpler expressions, however.

@Bill I should mention that I've also tried truncating the series using Normal[], after which I get something like "``.function(wolframclient.language.wl.Global.h)", \ "``.evaluate('DownValues[h] = {HoldPattern[h[_x]] :> integralresult}; \ OwnValues[integralresult] = HoldPattern[integralresult] :> " ... when attempting to use ToPythonFunction.

Have you considered using Wolfram from inside Python with Wolfram Client for Python? This way you would not need to convert the expression/function and can use its result in Python.

@Edmund Thanks for the suggestion! Regrettably, the code I'm writing is being contributed to a code base for which I'm told that I cannot add any new dependencies. All I have access to are a few standard Python libraries (NumPy, SciPy, etc).

Reading some of the documentation for ToPythonFunction seems to indicate that you can't expect this to be an expert Python programmer who will read your Mathematica code and figure out how to turn that into a complete Python program including code to implement custom functions. But I thought that might help you with some of your translation process if you could live with the limitations. Is there any way you could get around all those Sqrt[cc]? Tried to make integrand simpler, no luck, tried to make integrandExpansion simpler, less luck. Must get that for this to work. What to do now?

Convert Wolfram to LaTex using TeXForm and then in Python use latex2sympy to convert LaTex to Python.

@Edmund That worked, thanks! I had tried latex2sympy without success, but hadn't come across latex2sympy2. If you'd like to make that an answer I can accept it and then add the couple of lines of code that I used.

or you can use large language model, like chatgpt, gemini... ```expr = A Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2;
rewrite to pythonand it works.import numpy as np
def expr(A, x):
"""
Evaluates the expression A * sin(x)^2 + cos(x)^2.
Args:
A: A scalar value.
x: A scalar or numpy array representing the angle in radians.
Returns:
The result of the expression.
"""
return A * np.sin(x)**2 + np.cos(x)**2```

You can convert from Wolfram to LaTeX with TeXForm, or export the expression as a .tex file using Export.  Then use Python's latex2sympy2 to convert LaTeX to Python:
from latex2sympy2 import latex2sympy

integral_expr = r"..." # Insert LaTeX expression here
sympy_expr = latex2sympy(file_content)


Hope this helps.
